# jquery full calender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Currently my page has a jQuery Full Calendar and a button at the bottom of the page. The user selects a start and end date on the calendar by clicking and dragging, and clicks the button at the bottom of the page. I want to get the start and end date of the current selection on the jQuery full calendar in the button click function. Can any one tell me how I could grab the event start and event end date in the button click function.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the docs:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/startParam/

I assume one of the following can help you:
startParam, endParam, eventClick